# is splice 3rd parameter iaccepting any value?

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why newArr is not changing. Seems like my splice function isnt accepting "first13[index]" as argument. Though, when i change "index" to a fixed value, everything worck. I indeed consoleloged index, and it shows correct values as integer. Im really confused here. Any tips?

```
function rot13(str) {
  let first13 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'];
  let second13 = ['n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
  let newArr = str.toLowerCase().split('');
  let index = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<newArr.length; i++) {
    if(first13.indexOf(newArr[i]) != -1) {
      index = first13.indexOf(newArr[i]);
      newArr.splice(i, 1, first13[index]);
      console.log(newArr);       
    }  
  }
}
rot13("EBG13 rknzcyr.") // "ROT13 example.";
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?  What's your desired outcome?

Comment: I want to replace the letters passed as argument with the one in my arrays. For exemple, "a" become "n", because it's a +13 in the alphabet.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  As mentioned below, you're currently replacing characters with themselves.  There's also a shorter way to do this.  I'll included my code below, but feel free to use or don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code's working fine.
There is a mistake in your logic.
You are just replacing the element with the same.
For example you are replacing E with first13(index) which is E.
May be change `first13[index]` to `second13[index]` if you want to replace it with +13 characters.
EDIT: The above change must be made for parameter of splice() method.

Comment: I was so focus on the codding rules part that i forgot the logic one. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working exactly as it's coded as...

Dry running your code:

iteration 1:

```
index=0
i=0
if( first13.indexOf("e") != -1 )   //true
    {
    index = first13.indexOf("e")   //index = 4
    newArr.splice(0,1,first13[4])  //at 0th index remove one element and add first13[4] therefore newArr[0] becomes "e" from "e" (basically remains same)
    console.log(newArray) .        //printing the array which is same as before.
    }
```

iteration 2:

```
index=4                            //from last iteration
i=1
if( first13.indexOf("b") != -1 )   //true
    {
    index = first13.indexOf("e")   //index = 1
    newArr.splice(1,1,first13[1])  //at 1st index remove one element and add first13[1] therefore newArr[1] becomes "b" from "b" (basically remains same)
    console.log(newArray)          //printing the array which is same as before.
    }
```

After every iteration the array is same since you're replacing elements with same element, as seen above. Re write the logic. You haven't coded what you wanted to do...

Answer (score 0):

With the current setup, the code is just replacing letters in `newArr` with the same letter from `first13`.

When the code runs through the first time,

`index = first13.indexOf(newArr[i]);`

is setting `index = 4`, then

`newArr.splice(i, 1, first13[index]);`

is taking the letter at `first13[4]`, 'e' in this case, and replacing `newArr[0]`, which also happens to already be 'e'.

As Raj Datta Manohar suggested above, change the last property in your splice method to `second13[index]` and you should get something closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone here has already answered how to correct the logic in your code.  Below is just another way to approach the problem that might help in reading the logic because there's a little less going on.

```
function rot13(str) {
  let input = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  let output = 'NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm';
  let index = (x) => input.indexOf(x);
  let translate = (x) => index(x) > -1 ? output[index(x)] : x;
  console.log(str.split('').map(translate).join(''));
}

rot13("EBG13 rknzcyr."); // ROT13 example.
```